# opening default path for root user

Tags: arch-linux, zsh, path, prompt, oh-my-zsh

It may be trivial what I say, but I need to change the default opening path that OH My ZSH has. since no matter where I preposition myself in a file path (example: */home/username/Downloads/owt*), when starting root it always opens in my *"/home/username ~>"* folder

it's my first time using zsh in arch Linux... does anyone know how to change that default route?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could be put a `cd ~/Downloads/owt` command in your `~/.zprofile` file (which is run at login).

Be warned that this may confuse software (or people) that expects to start in your home directory by default.